# ORA-01450: maximum key length exceeded after SET max_string_size=extended

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle 12.2 PDB.

Regarding to [MAX_STRING_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.htm) I want to perform

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_string_size=extended SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

as described in part for CDB and PDB.

But I`m afraid of error

```
ORA-01450: maximum key length exceeded.
```

> Altering `MAX_STRING_SIZE` will update database objects and possibly invalidate them, as follows:
>
> - Tables with virtual columns will be updated with new data type metadata for virtual columns of `VARCHAR2(4000)`, 4000-byte `NVARCHAR2`, or `RAW(2000)` type.
>
>   - Functional indexes will become unusable if a change to their associated virtual columns causes the index key to exceed index key length limits. Attempts to rebuild such indexes will fail with `ORA-01450: maximum key length exceeded`.

How can I check indexes which are now in my PDB to see whether they will be affected?

Comment: To the people voting to move the question to dba.stackexchange: While the change of the setting is clearly a DBA task and decision, shouldn't we developers have the option to request a feature from the DBAs? For that, we would need a solid understanding of the implications...

Answer (score 2):

The change was performed just on PDB. 
For now the DB is working without any new errors.
Executing the **utl32k.sql** just don`t change setting on some materialized views.